# Wordpress remove_role() not working

Tags: wordpress, user-roles

Hi I'm trying to deleting some custom created roles with,

```
$wp_roles = new WP_Roles();
$wp_roles->remove_role("your_role");
```

Some roles deleted fine. but when I delete few otehr roles first time they seems to deleted successfully. but after next refresh they are recreating.

I'm pretty sure , this is not a something that is recreating the role if it is not exists. As I created those roles via add_role those roles are totally independent and no inside code creating those.

Thanks

I tried with "User Role Editor" plugin not worked too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the access to phpmyadmin, try editing the database directly.

**wp_user_roles** is in **wp_options** table.

Each user's role/capability is in a **wp_capabilities** record in **wp_usermeta**

There you can add/edit/delete any roles with minimum mysql knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this

```
//check if role exist before removing it
if( get_role('subscriber') ){
      remove_role( 'subscriber' );
}

//check if role exist before removing it
if( get_role('contributor') ){
      remove_role( 'contributor' );
}

//check if role exist before removing it
if( get_role('editor') ){
      remove_role( 'editor' );
}

//check if role exist before removing it
if( get_role('author') ){
      remove_role( 'author' );
}
```